# Python TCP port scanner

Tags: python, python-2.7, port, port-scanning

I'm trying to create a TCP port scanner in Python that accepts a number of arguments (-all (displays all ports, both open and closed for the target), -open (only displays the open ports on the target), -target (specify target IP, subnet or hostname) and -range (specify port range).

Currently I've only managed to code the options used in the program, my code is as follows:

```
import optparse

parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-all', dest='allPorts', help='displays all ports regardless of status')
parser.add_option('-open', dest='openPorts', help='displays only open ports')
parser.add_option('-target', type='string', dest='targetIP', help='specify target IP address, subnet or hostname')
parser.add_option('-range', type='string', dest='portRange', help='specify port range')

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

I'm unsure how to continue with the program, particularly with the -all / -open options, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: start with getting a filtered sub-list, containing all words for which the condition `'e' not in word` is `true`. Then, you'll need to do some Cartesian  multiplication of this list. You'll have `N^3` possible strings, where `N` is number of words after filtering

Comment: I think the most intuitive way to implemented is to use 3 nested for loops that all run on your filtered words, then just concatenate them and make the "find-replace" operations

Comment: When trying to crack (brute force) a password taking three random words from your file won't be of much use, you systematically need to try all possible combinations. Also is `randomwords.txt` the file with the story? If so, you should start by creating a set of candidate words (no duplicates, no words containing `e`, replace `o`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified one answer posted here, Actually i wanted to edit that answer but deleted by the author.
**Try Following:**

```
res = ""
for x in data[:3]:
    res += x
    res.replace("o", "0")
print res
```

OR

```
res = ""
for x in data[:3]:
    res = res + x
print res.replace("o", "0")
```

Try Last one.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to build a new string from several different strings:

```
''.join(data[:3])
```

and to replace `o` with `0` use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
''.join(data[:3]).replace('o', '0')
```

Note that you can get 3 samples with [`random.sample(data, 3)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample), you don't need to shuffle the complete `data`:

```
''.join(random.sample(data, 3)).replace('o', '0')
```

To exclude words containing `"e"` you can only keep words that **do not** contain `"e"` in the input:

```
with open('randomwords.txt', 'r') as f:
    # a conditional list comprehension
    data = [word for word in f.read().split() if "e" not in word]

[...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
"{}{}{}".format(w1,w2,w3).replace("o","0")
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your assignement seems to allow repetitions (e.g. passwords like "passw0rdpassw0rdpassw0rd") while your method doesn't. It is also inefficient. You can use `random.choice` three times instead.

Concatenation of strings is done with `+` operator, e.g. `concatenation = str1 + str2 + str3`, or `join` function. Replacing o with 0 is done with string class method `replace`, e.g. `concatenation.replace('o', '0')`.